# Text overlapping itself instead of going to next line

Tags: html, css

I have this very straightforward jumbotron class :

**HTML**

```
<div class="jumbotron">Welcome to my fake shop</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%
}

.jumbotron {
  background: blue;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 10vw;
  text-align:center;
}
```

It works perfectly fine and as expected in CodePen:
https://codepen.io/laudem/pen/ZExYvMZ

[image]

1. Div is taking all the place
2. Text is centered both vertically and horizontally
3. If the `font-size` get larger, the phrase wraps onto the next line

However, **this exact same code produces a different result in my code** (angular)
[image]

1. Div is taking all the place - Good
2. Text is centered, both vertically and horizontally - Good
3. But if the `font-size` gets larger, **instead of the phrase wrapping onto the new line, it overlaps the first one.**

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you please add some code of your angular component? (or wherever it gets rendered the page)
I tried on an Angular environment but I cannot reproduce the error

Comment: Set .jumbotron  line height

Comment: Can you try to add to your css the 'line-height: 20px' for example? I believe it has something to do with the line height of the text.

Comment: That was it @JaswinderKaur. Adding ```line-height: 1.5;``` did the trick! Thanks very much! Post it as an answer if you want me to accept it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Set line height **

```
.jumbotron {line-height:1.5;}
```